# Сравнения почтовых адресов

Tags: python, файлы

Имеется база данных эл. почт (txt формат). Пользователь отправляет свой адрес в функцию (например ample@mail.com). В базе содерится похожий (но не идентичный) ящик, с именем example@mail.com. Пользовательского ящика в базе нет! Программа должна вернуть false, т.к. ящики разные. Я написал простую функцию для проверки вхождения:

```
def check(email):
    with open("emails.txt", "r") as f:
        emails = f.read()
        if email in emails:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Проблема в том, что хотя адрес на совпадает, программа будет возвращать значение True, если адрес имя ящика совпадет с концовкой имени другого. Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: преобразуйте список адресов в лист

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что файл emails имеет вид:

```
example@mail.com:Вася
my@mail.com:Петя
```

тогда проверка будет примерно так, кстати, она соответсвует Вашему коду (без принтов, конечно)

```
def chek(email):
    with open("emails.txt") as f:
        return email in (s.split(':')[0] for s in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил через преобразование в список и последующее сравнение через `email == line[0]`

```
def check(email):
    with open("emails.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = list(line.split(":"))
            print(line)
            if email == line[0]:
                print(True)
                return True
```

Comment: ``list(line.split(":"))`` - list здесь лишнее. ``split()`` уже дает список.

Comment: `for line in f.readlines():` есть тоже лишнее, достаточно `for line in f:`